# Distribute ssh connections made by Django App (multi-threaded python function) among n number of Kubernetes Replicas

Tags: python, django, multithreading, ssh, kubernetes

My Django App makes SSH connections to n number of machines (using a multithreaded python function). When `replica=n` is set in kubernetes `deployment.yaml` file then I want my app to distribute the connections among the `n` replicas.

I mean 1 replica should connect to k number machines, another to next k number of machines and so on. When all the replicas are done then it should take the connections in cyclic fashion i.e. next k connections to first machine and another next k to other machine.

I tried with 2 replicas but all the connections are getting established by both the pods (replicas).

I want those connections to be distributed among the pods. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the replica count will not change after launch you can get this info from kube api and then have your pods run from statefulset so they have sequential ids, then use the good old trick of `mod N = 0..N-1` to divide work from the list in an even fashion and you should be fine.

Comment: @Goblin Thanks for answering but actually I did not get your answer completely. As you said -

1) If the replica count will not change after launch you can get this info from kube api 

--> As I mentioned in my question that I tried with 2 replicas but all the connections are getting established by both the pods (replicas). I can see 2 pods running with kubectl get pods. I entered int these pods and checked with ps -ef that if I both the pods were making ssh connections to all the machines.

Comment: Do you mean something else by "If the replica count will not change after launch you can get this info from kube api"?

Comment: 2) and then have your pods run from statefulset so they have sequential ids -

--> I am very new to kubernetes, can I please know how to run pods from statefulset?

3) then use the good old trick of mod N = 0..N-1 to divide work from the list in an even fashion and you should be fine.

--> How can I fit this suggestion into below piece of code?

Comment: `def handle_ssh(host):
 status = connection_manager.host_is_up(host.type, host.hostname)
 if status:
  try:
   conn = wvmHostDetails(host, host.login, host.password, host.type)
   info = conn.get_node_info()
   cpu = conn.get_cpu_usage()
   mem = conn.get_memory_usage()
   inst = conn.get_instances()
   mem_in_GB = info[2]/(1024*1024*1024)
   vms = ((host.name, host.id, status, info[3], cpu['usage'], info[2], mem['percent']), conn.get_instances())
   conn.close()             
 else:
  vms = ((host.name, host.id, status, 2, 0, 0, 0), None)
 return vms`

Comment: `def ssh_func():
 compute = Compute.objects.filter()
 vms = {}
 threads = 10
 from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
 pool = ThreadPool(threads)
 results = pool.map(handle_ssh,compute)
 pool.close()
 pool.join()`

Comment: @"Radek 'Goblin' Pieczonka" @Goblin Sorry but editing the comment here is a challenge here

Comment: @Goblin can you please explain your answer with example code?